# AppleScript POSIX path to smb path

Tags: applescript, smb

I want to create an automator service that copies the full `smb://` path of a folder or file (like you would get from <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

The reason the shortcut isn't enough is for all those "older people" (no offense intended) that can't remember shortcuts or don't want to use them at all (the typical rightclick -> copy instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> users).

So far I got the POSIX path but how do I transform it to my correct `smb://` path?

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
         set theItem to selection as string
    end tell
    set posixForm to POSIX path of theItem
    set the clipboard to posixForm
end run
```

So this path `/Volumes/someFolder/someSubFolder/` would become this `smb://Server/someFolder/someSubFolder/`

Comment: What are you going to do if the _"older people" (no offense intended)_ select more than one _file_? You should change `set theItem to selection as string` to `set theItem to first item of (selection as alias list)` so you do not have to worry about those _older people_! :)

Comment: Thank you! But I still need the translation to smb

Comment: The smb path is going to depend on the name of the share. How about asking us about what you're actually trying to achieve rather than how you think you'll achieve it?

Comment: Well, I want this path /Volumes/someFolder/someSubFolder/ to become this one smb://Server/someFolder/someSubFolder/ (or for the full story: Right click folder -> MyService -> smb path to clipboard

Comment: You'll probably need to **URL Encode** some _characters_ and _spaces_, however, here is a [link to some _example_ **AppleScript** _code_](https://paste.ee/p/nbFvM) that you may find helpful, although it only encodes _spaces_.

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you very much. Yesterday I took a quick look from my phone and saw the code. Today it's a 404. Did you create it? Would be great if you can update your link.

Comment: Copy it this time as it's an expiring link. https://paste.ee/p/R3eye

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you very much. Working great and helped me out. Post it as answer so I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to **URL Encode** some *characters* and *spaces*, however, here is some *example* **AppleScript** *code*  that you may find helpful, although it only encodes *spaces*:

```applescript
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    set theItem to the first item of ¬
        the (selection as alias list)

set posixForm to POSIX path of theItem

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, " "}
set foo to text items of posixForm
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "%20"
set foo to foo as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
set foo to text items 3 thru -1 of foo
set foo to foo as string
set smbForm to "smb://server/" & foo as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

set the clipboard to smbForm
```

---

**Notes:**

Have a look at [**Encoding and Decoding Text**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html) in the [**Mac Automation Scripting Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH56-SW1).

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>